# Jetpack Compose keyboard focus vs clickable indication highlight

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, accessibility

For a while I thought item focus is the same thing as focus highlight. But I am confused. I have this example below:

```
var color by remember { mutableStateOf(Green) }

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(color)
        .focusable()
        .onFocusChanged { color =
            if (it.isFocused)
                Blue
            else
                Green
        }
) {
    Text(
        text = "Some content",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1
    )
}
```

When I move the keyboard focus to this item, nothing happens. Even though I would have expected that the keyboard focus would actually - you know - focus on the item and the item's background would turn blue. But it does not.

If I add

```
.clickable {  }
```

on to this item, I can see that the keyboard focus is on this item by a grey'ish overlay. This is because it now uses the default Indication on this item. But also in this case, the color does not change.

So how do I focus on items in Compose? And how does keyboard focus relate to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the order of the focusable and the onFocusChanged modifier since the order of modifiers is important. As stated in this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186567354,

> The focus modifier holds the focus state. When focus state changes, it calls all focus modifers preceeding it.

So this should work:

```
var color by remember { mutableStateOf(Green) }

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(color)
        .onFocusChanged { color =
            if (it.isFocused)
                Blue
            else
                Green
        }
        .focusable()
) {
    Text(
        text = "Some content",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1
    )
}
```